# Why does strlen function not work in this for loop condition?

Tags: c, for-loop, strlen

I am learning C and I have question. In this exercise I have to program a game called double dutch where you learn to practice with strings. The problem I ran into is that the program stops executing because of the for loop condition (in the first for loop). The strlen() function works well in main and in the ayInFrontOfConsonant function at first when I print the length of the string but I don't get why the program stops working. In Xcode I get the message: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Any help is very much appreciated.

```
void ayInFrontOfConsonant(char *str) 
{
    char consonants[42] = { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 
'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'B', 
'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 
'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};


    int a=(int)strlen(str);

    printf("\n Length of str in ay function:   %d\n",a);

    int i=0,j=0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(str);i++)      //problem is here
    {
        for(j=0;j<strlen(consonants);j++)
        {
            if(str[i]==consonants[j])
            {
                //insertChar(str, 'a', i);

            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a=0;
    printf("** Welcome to the Double Dutch game **\n");
    char myString[36];
    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]s", myString);

    a=strlen(myString);
    printf("Length of string in main: %d\n",a);

    ayInFrontOfConsonant(myString);


    printf("Double dutch traslation: %s\n",myString);


    return 0;
```

}

Comment: What's your input?

Comment: The input I use is: "I like writing C code"

Comment: If you know what `strlen()` does, you wouldn't use it like that.

Comment: The problem is likely in `strlen(consonants)` where the string is not properly terminated.

Comment: Tip: `int a=strlen(str);` was incorrectly fixed. Use `size_t a=strlen(str);` instead of `int a=(int)strlen(str);`.

Comment: Ah... *that* `strlen`...

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]s", ...` means "match a non-empty sequence of characters other than a newline followed by an `s`". That's impossible, since a sequence of characters other than a newline must either be followed by a newline or appear at the end of file.

Comment: **strlen()** only works when a string is terminated with a null byte '\000'

Comment: You should use 'sizeof' instead of 'strlen'. And why not use 42 because you already used it and know the size of 'consonants'. And 42 is always a good way to go, it is an answer to life, universe and everything :D

Comment: @Urke if you are going to use `42` more than once, or even once, it is a "magic number" that should be defined.

Comment: Isn't there a function in string.h that checks if a string contains one of the chars of a second string?

Comment: @ikegami yes `strcspn` and `strspn` are inclusive and exclusive functions.

Comment: `consonants` is ***not*** as C-string, as it is missing the `0`-terminator. So *one may **not** use any `str*()` functions* on it.

Comment: @WeatherVane You are absolutely right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array has no `null` terminator.

Instead of that, use `sizeof consonants / sizeof *consonants` — or in this particular case since `sizeof *consonants` is surely `1`, then just `sizeof consonants`.

You should not use `strlen()` in the condition of a `for` loop, because it traverses the string every time, until it finds the `null` terminator which is missing in your

```
char consonants[42] = { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 
    'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'B', 
    'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 
    'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};
```

If you use

```
const char *consonant = "bcdf ...";
```

instead, the compiler will add the `'\0'` terminator, you can also add it explicitly

```
char consonants[] = { 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 
        'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'B', 
        'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 
        'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '\0'};
```

A [c](/questions/tagged/c) programmer would probably write this instead,

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void ayInFrontOfConsonant(char *str) 
{
    char consonants[] = {
        'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 
        'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'B', 
        'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 
        'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
    };

    for (size_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof consonants; ++j) {
            if (str[i] == consonants[j]) {
                // Do here whatever you wanted to do
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But not really, because there is no need to scan the whole array of consonants since they can be sorted and you can use *binary search* which would improve the algorithm a lot.

Comment: Note that the `sizeof(constonants)/sizeof(*constonant)` technique only works if constonants is an array.   Pass it as an argument to a function, and it will be converted to a pointer, and the technique will not work (so length needs to be passed a different way).

Answer (score 2):

When you write a statement like `char consonants [42] = { ... }`, one of three things happen:

If you have 43 or more characters, the compiler gives you an error.

If you have 41 or less characters, the compiler fills the rest of the array with zeroes, and `strlen()` will work because there is a nul byte after the characters.

If you have exactly 42 characters, the compiler fills the array exactly to the end. There is no trailing zero byte. `strlen` will not work.

In reality, there was no reason for you to count the characters.

```
char consonants [] = "bcdfgh..."
```

would do exactly what you want.

Comment: Re "*would do exactly what you want*", A better fix is actually to keep the array, but use `sizeof` instead of `strlen`.